# Django-rest post returns get

Tags: django-rest-framework

I built out an API with django-rest, tested it on a local machine, and pushed it to my PaaS.  On my local machine a view associated with a post works perfectly. The live site throws an error.

Decorator for view in question: `@api_view(['POST'])`

```
Error: u'{"detail":"Method \\"GET\\" not allowed."}'.
```

Python Request Module snippet (note POST not get):

```
r = requests.post(my_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Server log: `"POST /api/xxx/xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 301`

No errors in the server log, no errors in the django-rest API.  The post to the function does work on the browsable API.  Why am I receiving a GET error on a post? I've tried things in curl and receive the same error. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  Move from http to https wasn't reflected in the URL.

Comment: fixed my problem, was stuck on an issue like this for almost an hour. thanks for updating!